# Can't run PHP file with apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I want to set up php on my machine but I can't make it work. This is what I did:

1. I downloaded php with `sudo apt-get php`
2. Installed Apache `sudo apt install apache2`
3. Resterted server `sudo service apache2 restart`
4. Both `http://localhost/` and `php -v` work as the should

But when I try to run a basic php file it doesn't work. For example in `/var/www/html` I have following `test.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<?php
echo '<p> HEY </p>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I type in my browser `http://localhost/test.html` I get some garbage:

```
HEY
'; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, apache will not run files with the extension `html` through PHP. Try renaming your file to `test.php` and call `http://localhost/test.php`

- To run `html` files through PHP, adapt the mime settings
- To make `index.php` the default directory index adapt the `index` settings